# Specifying custom resource file for an ASP.NET page/usercontrol

Tags: asp.net, localization, resourcemanager, resource-file

If I have a page called Default.aspx, ASP.NET automatically uses the resource file named Default.aspx.resx in App_LocalResources for localizing server controls in the page.

But for some reason, I need to choose another file, let's say Default-Custom.aspx.resx. To provide some background, I already have Default.aspx.resx but some users need to have different content shown to them, which I am going to put in Default-Custom.aspx.resx.

Is is possible to choose the Resource file used for a TemplateControl in ASP.NET (short of writing a custom ResourceProvider)??

Comment: Hmmm... I have already written a custom ResourceProvider/ResourceManager and other supporting infrastructure to achieve what I needed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look here:

[ResourceManager.GetResourceFileName Method](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/wwdbresourceprovider/#Creating_a_custom_Resource_Provider)

> This method uses CultureInfo 's Name
>   property as part of the file name for
>   all cultures other than the invariant
>   culture. This method does not look in
>   an assembly's manifest or touch the
>   disk, and is used only to construct
>   what a resource file name (suitable
>   for passing to the ResourceReader
>   constructor) or a manifest resource
>   blob name should be.
>
> A derived class can override this
>   method to look for a different
>   extension, such as ".ResX", or a
>   completely different scheme for naming
>   files.

You can try something like this:

```
public class ResxResourceManager : ResourceManager
{  
    protected override string GetResourceFileName(
         System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return base.GetResourceFileName(culture);       
    }

    public string GetResxFileName(System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return GetResourceFileName(culture).Replace(".resources", ".resx");
    }
}
```

For more on this:

[Creating a custom Resource Provider](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/wwdbresourceprovider/#Creating_a_custom_Resource_Provider)

[Under the Hood of BuildManager and Resource Handling](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/aspnet_resxmocking.aspx?display=PrintAll)

Comment: Thanks for replying Leniel. As I mentioned in my comment to the original post, I have already written a custom ResourceProvider for myself that can parse out resources in an extremely deep and complex hierarchy based on my needs.

Further, it can work on .resx files (in a WSP environment) as well as .resources (in a completely pre-compiled or WAP environment).

Thanks for your comment none-the-less.

Comment: @r_honey: I didn't see that the comment was yours... :)

Comment: I have accepted this post as the answer as it correctly provides a solution to the question asked (although I should have framed it better as my needs were different :))

Comment: Thanks to Leniel for answering the question, with some extra reading material, and r_honey for leaving the question up.  This helps others coming along later with the same questions, like me :).