# Localization Service with Telerik MVC Controls

Tags: localization, telerik, telerik-mvc

We are using the Telerik MVC controls (not Kendo at the moment) which are localized to ResX files. We have a requirement to use a localization service provided by our clients instead.

How can we tell Telerik to use something other than a ResX file for localization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to create a custom resource provider, which is basically covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583529/specifying-custom-resource-file-for-an-asp-net-page-usercontrol).

Comment: That was indeed how we fixed it in the end. Thanks for the link.